# How to persist redux state between redux @init runs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reset

I have a React app that uses redux.js. I have a timeoutMonitor function that runs when a user does not complete a task in a designated timeframe. It dispatches a redux action (`logoutUser()`), and then sets an error in my homepageSlice in redux so that an message will be displayed on the homepage.

```
const timeoutUser = () => {
    dispatch(logoutUser()) // logs out user and sets the url back to the hompage
    updateHomePageMessage('Session has timed out') // updates homepageMessage in redux homepageSlice

}
```

The problem is that once the user is logged out, redux @INIT runs so any message I set for my user is reset. I do want @INIT to run so other redux slices are properly reset.

Ideas I've considered so far:

- dispatch logoutUser and set a function that then calls updateHomePageMessage once @INIT runs (not quite sure how to do this besides setTimeout, which feels clunky)
- move updateHomePage outside of redux and into Homepage component state and preserve this information through a useRef and passing an update function down via props
- find a way to persist homepageMessage in redux despite @INIT, if this is even possible

Is there a way that is considered best practice? I'd be grateful for any advice. Thank you!

Comment: Did you know why  @INIT runs when you logout ? did you refresh the page or someting similar ?

Comment: Did you have a codesandbox with a reproduction ? So we know more about your setup

Answer (score 0):

### Feedback based on the different approach

> dispatch logoutUser and set a function that then calls updateHomePageMessage once @INIT runs (not quite sure how to do this besides setTimeout, which feels clunky)

I do not recommend you this one, this is considered as an anti-pattern: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/186

> move updateHomePage outside of redux and into Homepage component state and preserve this information through a useRef and passing an update function down via props

This is a possible solution, but it's possible to do it with redux by persisting your slice, as this information is beneficial for your whole app, it's better to keep it in redux

> find a way to persist homepageMessage in redux despite @INIT, if this is even possible

You can do this with redux-persist.

### How to persist redux state in local storage ?

You can use redux persist to persist slice inside the localstorage and having them when you reload the page https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Then you will always keep in the localstorage the homepageMessage when you refresh the page